# Locus of complex solutions of $(z+i)^{2011}=z^{2011}$

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

> What do the complex solutions of $(z+i)^{2011}=z^{2011}$ lie on?

1. Hyperbola
2. Ellipse
3. Straight line
4. Circle

I do not know how to approach it.

Comment: Take the modulus...

Comment: Yeah, take the modulus and and interpret this as the locus of points equidistant from $0$ and $-i$. What do you think is the answer now?

Comment: That was a cool one, zwim!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** This is equivalent (why ?) to
$$\left( \frac{z+i}{z}\right)^{2011}=1$$

i.e. to : there exists $k \in \lbrace 0, ..., 2010 \rbrace$ such that
$$ \frac{z+i}{z} = \exp\left(\frac{2ik\pi}{2011} \right)$$

Now you can solve that in $z$.

Comment: "The options are hyperbola, ellipse, straight line and circle" So you shifted that decision from an implicit to an explicit(?) expression, congrats!

Comment: @ProfessorVector I just gave a hint, indicating that the equation can be solved explicitely... Once you solved it, it is easy to see where do the solutions lie.

Comment: Is it, now? Considering the comment of @user35508, the explicit form is just a waste of time and effort.

Comment: No. The comment gives that one of the options is correct, but does not show that the other options are wrong. You have to work further to see that there are sufficiently many distinct solutions so the different options cannot happen simultaneously.

Comment: No, it didn't :(